# python scraping error AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Tags: beautifulsoup, scrapy, web-crawler, mechanize

I am doing python scraping with beautiful soup, the website i am crawling has a 28 container with title, link and text, the text is in `<p>`tag, my problem is I can crawl all the data but some `<p>` tags has no text, so I receive an error
`"AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'"`
my code is:

```
containers = page_soup.findAll("div", {"class":"item-container"})


for contain in containers:


    title = contain.div.a.h3.text

    print("title: "+title)

    link = contain.div.a["href"]

    print("source: "+link)

    des = contain.div.p.text
   
    print("Description: "+des)
```

it print 5 times `<p>` tag text, because not all of the `<p>` tag has text, but it gives me error, how to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like below to accomplish the task:

```
for contain in page_soup.find_all("div", {"class":"item-container"}):
    title = contain.div.a.h3.text
    link = contain.div.a["href"]
    try:
        des = contain.div.p.text
    except:
        des = ""
    print("title: {}\nlink: {}\ndescription: {}\n".format(title,link,des))
```

Comment: it works well, can I print "No-Description" in except clause?